Probability of the correct answer being a Condorcet winner
You have a question with $k$ possible answers, and you ask $n$ people what they think the answer is. Everyone provides their (strict) ranking of all the answers. What is the probability that the correct answer is a Condorcet winner?
With probability $p$ they know the correct answer, and they will rank the correct answer highest, and order everything else uniformly randomly. Otherwise they order all the answers uniformly randomly.
A Condorcet winner is an answer that wins a pairwise vote against any other option: i.e. for any other answer $a$, a majority of people rank it above $a$.
By the Law of Large Numbers, as $n \to \infty$ the probability goes to $1$, because the probability of losing a vote against any alternative $a$ goes to $0$. The probability of a given person voting for the correct answer in a pairwise vote is $p + \frac12 (1-p) > \frac12$ so the proportion of correct answers converges in probability to a number $> \frac12$.
I would like to generalise the problem to allow any distribution $f(x)$ of the position in the order of the correct answer. Where the position of the correct answer is chosen according to the distribution, then the ordering of the other answers is chosen uniformly at random. the above case is for $f(x) = \frac{1-p}{k}$ if $x \ne 1$ and $f(x) = \frac{1-p}{k} + p$ if $x=1$ (I am terming $1$ the highest rank). As long as the expected rank of the correct answer is less than $\frac{k+1}{2}$, it has probability $> \frac12$ of being chosen over any other answer pairwise, so my above LLN proof generalises to this case.
It is this general case that I am most interested in. But results for specific cases are of interest.
I assume exact formulas are impossible for $k>2$, but I would like to get a better idea of how quickly the probability of the right answer being a Condorcet winner goes to $1$. So I want any proof bounding the rate of convergence, or any upper or lower bounds for the function $q(n)$ specifying the probability of the correct answer being a Condorcet winner. Ideally for the more general question.

Another special case:
If $f(x)$ is made from the binomial distribution $Bin(k-1, p)$ this is equivalent to independently choosing, for each person, where an alternative $a$ is ranked over the correct answer. So each pairwise election is independent. The number of votes for the correct answer in a given pairwise election is $X \sim Bin(n, p)$ so the probability of winning the election is $P(Bin(n,p) > \frac12 n)$ and the probability of being a Condorcet winner is $P(Bin(n,p) > \frac12 n)^{k-1}$.
